# How do I extract the audio signal from displayport?

Tags: displayport, audio

I have a macbook pro with minidisplayport (MDP) out.  It's plugged into an external monitor.  Sometimes via MDP-to-DualDVI, and sometimes directly via MDP.  I'd like to extract the digital audio signal from the MDP connection.  I've seen cables that go from MDP to DVI+Audio.  I want a cable that goes from MDP to MDP+Audio so that I can feed the audio into something other than my Apple Cinema display (which has cruddy speakers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don´t assume anyone to ever build a mini DisplayPort to miniDisplayPort+Audio Adapter, and the option of going mini-DP<>Dual DVI<>mini-DP seems to be [quite expensive and bulky](http://www.atlona.com/Atlona-Dual-Link-DVI-to-Mini-DisplayPort-Converter-USB-Powered.html), why don´t you simply use the optical audio from your MacBook Pro´s audio output?

Comment: Two things I'm look for are: 1) not having one extra attachment every time I move the laptop from work to home. 2) Better quality audio.  I hadn't thought about your suggestion, but it gets me #2, and it's better than what I'm doing now!  But I'll still buy a MDP -> MDP+Audio cable if anyone makes one.